# FreshTomato: Configure second wireless AP on the same network as the primary, but with no internet access

Tags: router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

*[I'm using FreshTomato v2022.5 on a Netgear R6400v2, but I can upgrade to a newer version if needed, that is just the last time I touched the router]*

I'm trying to set up a second AP that's meant for shitty IoT devices that require WiFi to be used, but which I don't want to allow to access the internet. What I'd like to do is to create the AP in such a way that it's on the same network as the primary, ie. the phone connects to `MyAP` and can see the IoT device on the local network and access the internet, whereas the device connects to `MyAP-isolated` and can see the phone on the local network, but *cannot* route outside of the local network range. I tried creating a virtual wireless interface for that, but I quickly realised I have no idea what I'm doing. I'd appreciate any help in configuring it.

If I'm asking for something that isn't the best approach for what I'm trying to achieve, I'll be glad to change my strategy, but ultimately, I'd prefer to have a solution that doesn't require any further per-device setup. A non-routed network wouldn't require me to remember to do anything else, I just give the bad device that SSID and I'm done; I can't misconfigure it once I have that SSID set up. It also provides a rudimentary form of isolation should one of the famously well-secured devices be compromised.